# Is it possible to use custom directives as cell editor and cell render for ngHandsOnTable?

Tags: angularjs, handsontable

I am trying to use handsontable the angular version however there are no code samples to use a custom directive as a cell renderer or a cell editor for a particular cell. Any advise for this would be great. What i am trying to achieve is use to custom widgets for editiong and showing inside cells of handsontable